convergence of an infinite sum of exponentials
Suppose we have a series
$$ f(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \exp(-a_i x) $$
with each $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$.
Is the following true?
Either the series diverges for all $x \ge 0$, or there exists some $R > 0$ such that the series converges for $x > R$ and diverges for $0 \le x \le R$.

One can imagine the case where all the $a_i$ are negative, in which case you'd need to ask about $x < -R$.

I could ask about that, and maybe I should, but for my application I only care about nonnegative $x$.  If the series does not diverge for all $x \ge 0$, then I believe the $a_i$ must be bounded below, and only finitely many can be less than any $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Seems right to me as if the series converges for a given x>0 then  at most finitely many $a_i$ are negative or null.

Here's a negative answer to my own question, thanks to Oscar Cunningham.  He found a series
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \exp(-a_n x) $$
with each $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ for which it's

not true that the series diverges for all $x \ge 0$, and

not true that exists some $R > 0$ such that the series converges for $x > R$ and diverges for $0 \le x \le R$.


(I'm using $n$ to stand for what was $i+1$ in my original question.)
We take $a_n$ such that
$$ \exp(-a_n) = \frac{1}{n (\ln n)^2} $$
so
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \exp(-a_n x) = 
 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^x (\ln n)^{2 x}}
$$
This converges for $x \ge 1$ and diverges for $0 \le x < 1$.
